# Android life cycle method

Tags: android

Hi
What are the android life cycle method executed when an activity is started from another activity and also the method that should be executed in corresponds to home button click.
Is there any way to detect that user has pressed a home button ?
is there exist any unique method thatexecute as part of home button,am not meaning home button listener?

Answer (score 3):

[Android Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).  OnCreate is called on the new activity, onPause on the old one.

You can't capture the home button press, or do anything with it, but [onUserLeaveHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint%28%29) is called as an fyi.

Comment: is there exist any method that invoke as part of home button,am not meaning the home button listener,ie any other method that's unique to home button

Comment: onUserLeaveHint is the only method that I'm aware of.  I don't think it gets called for anything other than clicking home.

Comment: onUserLeaveHint is invoke as part of onpause it's not unique for home button .for every new intent ,casue onpause in old intent executed so it's also executed.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for it?  It clearly states that it is only called when the activity goes into the background as a result of user choice (i.e. hitting the home button), not every time onPause is called.  If it is called, it is called right before onPause, but it will not be called every time.

Comment: @Sudeep SR I think I see your issue now.  onUserLeaveHint is called at two different times, when the user hits home, or when you start a new activity.  It is not called if they get a phone call/text, hit back, etc.  The only way I can tell to see if it is home and not a new activity is to keep track yourself of when you are about to start activities.