# Android startActivity vs HOME Button

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume, android-homebutton, application-restart

I have a mainactivity. In the AndroidManifest I have declared.

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

This should bring me to this activity, every time the app is ended with the HOME Button and call onRestart() then, right?

Furthermore my mainactivity starts some other activitys by using

```
startActivity(...)
```

after calling this, mainactivity goes to onStop() and if i press Back in the ChildActivity, the mainactivity goes in onRestart(..).
Is there no chance to decide in my mainactivity whether the User pressed back on a ChildActivity or pressed home?

Comment: You could look at Activity.onUserLeaveHint() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserLeaveHint() and onKeyPressed() also this Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351041/android-life-cycle-method

Comment: @blundell onUserLeaveHint() is also called if my mainactivity starts another activity..

Comment: Yes, but you know if your main activity starts another activity as you coded it to do so ....

Comment: @Blundell Ok, but the OnUserLeaveHint() of MainActivity isn't called, if a childactivity is paused by HOME button. So every activity has to implement the OnUserLeaveHint() Method, which is not nice

Comment: Ay but it is an answer. That's why I put it in a comment and not a full blown answer :p